# How compare two strings and count the number of matched characters?

Tags: excel, string

I want to compare two strings in different cells (in order), and the return value is the number of matched characters.

The characters are limited to: A, B, C, D and E. They are alternatives of a test.

For example:

cell A1: DCBCCBD (the candidate's answers)

cell B1: BABCDBD (the correct answers)

He just asked the third, fourth and sixth question correct.

Then, I need to return in cell C1: **3** (the number of correct answers).

How can I do in MS Excel?

Comment: You can write a simple VBScript function that gets both cells as an input, has a simple `for` loop to iterate over the strings and tally up the correct answers, and output that tally.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: I suggest separating all characters into separate cells using [text to columns](https://www.exceldemy.com/split-text-in-excel-by-number-of-characters/#2_Use_Text_to_Column_Feature_to_Split_Text_in_Excel_by_Number_of_Characters), then it's much easier to compare the given answers to the correct answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `MID()` with `SEQUENCE()` then sum true values.

```
=SUM(--(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)=MID(B1,SEQUENCE(LEN(B1)),1)))
```

`--` suppress Boolean output to equivalent number values to sum.

[image]

Comment: Good job on posting an answer almost identical to mine, just 2 hours later and using a formula that is less compatible with prior versions of Excel....

Comment: @pgSystemTester You formula is complicated and will take more time to execute. Anyone can post better formula to any post. Do you discourage to post better answers? `FILTER()` formula is not compatible for prior versions. Always appreciate better answers, even over accepted answers.

Comment: `Filter` is compatible with Excel 2019, `Sequence` is not.  And my VBA approach is compatible back to 2007...  I have given all kinds of competing answers up ticks when they add any value. You've posted two answers today *hours* after mine that add zero if not negative improvement, yet are oddly similar.  If you're going to post an answer hours after one exists, at least make it a different approach. Both of yours were so similar (I would argue slightly worse). Yes, you can post what you want, just as I can comment on your answer's lack of merit.

Comment: @pgSystemTester Yes, I am agree with you. But there is significant improvement between your formula and mine. Please test execution time.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. I think you are shortchanging your candidate in that he or she got 4 correct.

```
=SUM(FILTER(--(MID(A1,ROW(A:A),1)=MID(B1,ROW(A:A),1)),ROW(A:A)<=LEN(A1)))
```

[image]

Here's a VBA custom function as mentioned in comments.

```
Function compareTexts(oneText As String, twoText As String) As Long
Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.Min(Len(oneText), Len(twoText))
        If Mid(oneText, i, 1) = Mid(twoText, i, 1) Then
            compareTexts = compareTexts + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! There are 4 questions correct, my mistake.

Comment: `ROW(A:A)` is an array comprising 1,048,576 cells. By referencing it 3 times, you are forcing your construction to evaluate more than 3 million calculations.

Comment: @JosWoolley, false. The 2 inner filtered calcs are after the filter so the calculation is effecient once made. The actual filter does appear to operate on  `FFFFF` rows but when you scope a whole column, excel's inner workings evaluate the `UsedRange` not the entire column.

Comment: @pgSystemTester Evaluation over the used range only applies to some functions, for example `COUNTIFS`, though not to `FILTER`. You can prove this quite easily: in a blank workbook, enter the formula `=SUM(FILTER($A:$A,$A:$A=""))` into cell `J1` and then copy to a modest number of cells, 500 say, e.g. to `J1:AC25`, and watch Excel calculate away. Recall that column A is completely empty, yet Excel needs close to 10 seconds for a full calculation. Now replace those 500 formulas with `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"")` - the calculation time is close to zero.

Comment: @JosWoolley, interesting observations although what I was more surprised by than your example was that Filter does not retain the filtered value for subsequent calcs in the formula. Probably why Microsoft introduced the `Let` function not long after. Thanks for insight.